# Unable to start JBoss

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I was working on JBoss and had included some jars recently(jbossws-core.jar,jbossws-common.jar,jbossws-spi.jar) in jbossws folder of deploy.sar. It was working fine for sometime and then suddenly stated throwing the following error:

```
10:12:47,482 WARN  [BasicMBeanRegistry] preRegister() failed for jbss.system:service=ServiceController:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.PropertyEditors.init()V
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.<clinit>(ServiceConfigurator.java:88)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.preRegister(ServiceController.java:749)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invokePreRegister(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:966)
    at org.jboss.mx.modelmbean.ModelMBeanInvoker.invokePreRegister(ModelMBeanInvoker.java:489)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.preRegister(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:654)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.invokePreRegister(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:697)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.registerMBean(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl$3.run(MBeanServerImpl.java:1422)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1417)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.createMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:295)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.createMBean(ServerImpl.java:543)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:442)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
   10:12:47,498 INFO  [ServiceController] Registration of ServiceController failed
Failed to boot JBoss:
javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Cannot register MBean:     jboss.system:service=ServiceController
    at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.registerMBean(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:314)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl$3.run(MBeanServerImpl.java:1422)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1417)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.createMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:295)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.createMBean(ServerImpl.java:543)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:442)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.management.RuntimeErrorException
    at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.invokePreRegister(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:725)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.registerMBean(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:211)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.PropertyEditors.init()V
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.<clinit>(ServiceConfigurator.java:88)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.preRegister(ServiceController.java:749)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invokePreRegister(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:966)
    at org.jboss.mx.modelmbean.ModelMBeanInvoker.invokePreRegister(ModelMBeanInvoker.java:489)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.preRegister(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:654)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.invokePreRegister(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:697)
    ... 23 more
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I was getting the same error on using a new fresh JBoss. Am working on Eclipse IDE 3.4

Would appreciate some help !!!
Thanks
-Aj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like your class path changed. Did you accidentally delete a jar? I would go back to the jboss website and get a fresh copy of jboss.

Comment: I feel I have deleted some important jar from jbossws folder. I'd infact replaced jboss-core.jar with the latest one after which it started I guess. Took a new copy of JBoss and copy pasted the new jbossws folder in the old JBoss and it started working.

Comment: glad to help. Sometimes slowing down and actually *looking* at the error message helps. Had a similar case for myself recently. Posted a question and a response pointed to the documentation just 3 lines below where i had looked. 

It would be nice if the NoSuchMethodError message would just say "Did the jar with this class get moved or deleted/ Please double-check your classpath."